# How to iterate in a file inside a function in Python3?

Tags: python, file, stream, iteration

I have this function where I open two files, one for reading and one for writing. I iterate through `input_file` and I write some items from it to the `save_file`.

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as source, open(save_file, 'w') as dest:
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        writer = csv.writer(dest)
        
        for row in reader:
            #do_something

            find_min(save_file, threshold)
```

Although through the iteration I want to call another function and iterate through the items that I have appended on the `save_file`, but when i call it and try to print them nothing is printed.

This is the function that I call:

```
def find_min(file, threshold):

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in reader:
            print(i)
```

If I try to call `find_min` function outside of `with` statement, the file is iterated normally and it's printed.

But I want to call this function a lot of times in order to analyze and compress the initial data.

So, does anyone know how to to iterate through the `save_file` in `find_min` function.

Comment: If you can fit all the data you write to `save_file` in memory (in a list) as well, you would be better off iterating over that list. Opening a file for write does not guarantee anything is actually written until the file is closed.

Comment: I dont want to create a list because it will slow down the whole program

Comment: But surely iterating over a file will be slower that iterating a list.

Comment: I agree but because I work with big files, I dont want to overload the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not closed the output file (or flushed its contents to disk), so it cannot not be reliably read until it is closed. The solution is to open the file for writing and reading using flag `w+`:

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as source, open(save_file, 'w+') as dest:
```

And then passing to `find_min` `dest`:

```
find_min(dest, threshold)
# make sure we are once again positioned at the end of file:
# probably not necessary since find_min reads the entire file
# dest.seek(0, 2) 

def find_min(dest, threshold):
    dest.seek(0, 0) # seek to start of file for reading
    reader = csv.reader(dest)
    for i in reader:
        print(i)
    # we should be back at end of file for writing, but if we weren't, then: dest.seek(0, 2)
```

**If `find_min` does not leave `dest` positioned at the end of file by not reading through the entire file, then a call to `dest.seek(0, 2)` must be made before resuming writing to ensure that we are first positioned at the end of file.**